# Change Index Template Across Elasticsearch Cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm running ES cluster with multiple on AWS. The cluster is behind an ELB that is fed by logstash. I've tested a new mapping template in a sandbox cluster, but with only one node.

I've read over these two articles:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime

When changing the template does each node need to have an updated copy? Can the new template be fed to the master and then it will share the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add/update your template using the `_template` endpoint and all master-eligible nodes will record it.

However, if you decide to store that template [within a file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html#config) (in the `config/templates` folder), then you have to store that file on all master-eligible nodes.

Comment: thanks! Changing with the _template endpoint propagated the changes through the entire cluster